# Spanish characters not being displayed on the terminal in python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, nltk

I downloaded Spanish text from NLTK in python using

```
spanish_sents=nltk.corpus.floresta.sents()
```

when printing the sentences in the terminal the corresponding Spanish characters
are not rendered. For example printing `spanish_sents[1]` produces characters like `u'\xe9'` and if I encode it using utf-8 as in

```
print [x.encode("utf-8") for x in sapnish_sents[1]]
```

it produces `'\xc3\xa9'` and encoding in latin3

```
print [x.encode("latin3") for x in sapnish_sents[1]]
```

it produces `'\xe9'`

How can I configure my terminal to print the glyphs for these points? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just an initial remark, Latin3 or [ISO-8859-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-3) is indeed denoted as South European, but it was designed to cover Turkish, Maltese and Esperanto. Spanish is more commonly encoded in Latin1 (ISO-8859-1 or West European) or Latin9 (ISO-8859-15).

I can confirm that the letter `é` has the unicode code point U+00E9, and is represented as `'\xe9'` in both Latin1 and Latin3. And it is encoded as `'\xc3\xc9'` in UTF8, so all your conversions are correct.

But the real question *How can I configure my terminal... ?* is hard to answer without knowing what the terminal is...

- if it is a true teletype or old vt100 without accented characters: you cannot (but I do not think you use that...)
- if you use a Windows console, declare the codepage 1252 (very near to Latin1): `chcp 1252` and use Latin1 encoding (or even better `'cp1252'`)
- if you use xterm (or any derivative) on Linux or any other Unix or Unix-like, declare an utf8 charset with `export LANG=en_US.UTF8` (choose your own language if you do not like american english, the interesting part here is `.UTF8`) and use UTF8 encoding - alternatively declare a iso-8859-1 charset (`export LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-1`) and use Latin1 encoding

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking at, is the representation of strings, because printing lists is only for debugging purposes.

For printing lists, use `.join`:

```
print ', '.join(sapnish_sents[1])
```

Comment: Main point is: the representation form escapes the non-ASCII characters. Encoding the output to match the terminal configuration will still be necessary, unless the defaults match by chance.

Comment: spanish_sents is a list of sentences. Printing the list using .join() works. However when I tried with another set such as

Comment: spanish_sents is a list of sentences. Printing the list using .join() works. However when I tried with another set such as spanish_sents=nltk.corpus.cess_esp.sents() , I'm getting UnicodeEncodeError  for \u0144'  with only some sentences when I use join(). I am using python 2.7 in miniconda

Comment: @Holly16 Have you tried `sapnish_sents[1].decode('utf-8')`?

Comment: @Holly16 Try `' '.join(spanish_sents).encode('utf8')` instead. If this works, but you get the wrong characters, try with `'latin1'`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there are a few things going on. First, you're iterating through a `str` (is `sapnish_sents[1]` one entire entry? What happens when you print that). Second, you're not getting full characters because you're iterating through a `str` (a unicode character takes more "space" than an ASCII character, so addressing a single index will look weird). Third you are trying to `encode` when you probably mean to `decode`.

Try this:

```
 print sapnish_sents[1].decode('utf-8')
```

I just ran the following in my terminal to help give context:

```
>>> a = '®†\¨ˆø' # Storing non-ASCII characters in a str is ill-advised;
                 # I do this as an example because it's what I think your question is
                 # really asking
>>> a # a now looks like a bunch of gibberish if I just output
'\xc2\xae\xe2\x80\xa0\\\xc2\xa8\xcb\x86\xc3\xb8'
>>> print a # Well, this looks normal.
®†\¨ˆø
>>> print repr(a) # Just demonstrating how the above works
'\xc2\xae\xe2\x80\xa0\\\xc2\xa8\xcb\x86\xc3\xb8'
>>> a[0] # We're only looking at one character, which is represented by all this stuff.
'\xc2' 
>>> print a[0] # But because it's not a complete unicode character, the terminal balks
?
>>> print a.decode('utf-8') # Look familiar?
®†\¨ˆø
>>> print a.decode('utf-8')[0] # Our first character!
®
```

Comment: The OPs text seems to be unicode strings already (see `u'\xe9'`), so decoding that is a confusing suggestion.

Comment: I think it's very bad practice (and very confusing to newcomers) to create byte strings with non-ASCII characters, like '®†\¨ˆø'. I can't think of a use-case where this would be the right thing to do. Create unicode strings (`u''`) if it's text.

Comment: @lenz OP's comments suggest that they have `str(u'<something>')`, not `u'\xe9'`. This means they are slicing a `str` and so getting wonky results. They need to convert it to a unicode object in order to get the full value at their indexes.

Comment: @lenz And it's _HORRIBLE_ practice to try to store unicode in a `str`. That's why `str` became unicode in Py3k. However, since it looks like this is exactly what the OP is doing, this example tries to show why he's getting that result.

Comment: @lenz That first paragraph explains both of my comments, BTW.

Comment: I still think the (wonderfully named :-D) `sapnish_sents` contain unicode strings, don't see why you think otherwise. But anyway, your additional comments are good.

Comment: @lenz Because he said `'\xe9'` not `u'\xe9'` and because that's exactly the type of behavior I would expect for indexed `str`s.

Comment: He (or she) reports `'\xe9'` as the output of `x.encode('latin3')`. That's what you get when `x` is `u'\xe9'`. If `x` is the byte `'\xe9'`, you get a UnicodeDecodeError instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130137/discussion-between-lenz-and-cwallenpoole).