# My python program does not write the accents in the Spanish language

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

this is my code

```
import pyautogui
import time

f = open('spambot\spam.txt', 'r')
time.sleep(5)  

for words in f:
    print(words)
    pyautogui.typewrite(words)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    time.sleep(3)
```

the content of spam.txt is this

"Yo sé que no me te importó"

but this is what it prints

"Yo s que no te import"

Comment: This is not the Python problem, but the terminal configuration problem. A similar question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033023/spanish-characters-not-being-displayed-on-the-terminal-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can edit this line adding an encoding that is appropriate for Spanish: 'utf', 'utf-8' or 'utf-8-sig' work fine:
`f = open('spam.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig')`